# Managing task queues in a multi-tenant application - GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, multi-tenant, task-queue

I have to implement recurring tasks in a multi-tenant environment on AppEngine. The real use case is 'implement recurring invoices'.

I am doubting 3 approaches, from centrally managed to decentralized per namespace to decentralized per scheduled task. Seeking feedback.

- **Centrally managed** : there is a 'main task queue' or cron job that periodically checks for which namespace jobs must be executed and then kicks them off. Per namespace look for tasks to be done.
- **Decentralized per namespace** : there is a task or cron job per namespace that periodically checks for the namespace it belongs to what needs to be done.
- **Decentralized per task** : when a new job is created in a namespace, immediately schedule a task queue for that task at the desired point in the future. No 'managing' task queue.

I am posing myself questions over each approach :

- **Centrally managed** : CONTRA -> does not scale, it requires iterating over all 'customer' namespaces. PRO -> easier to manage/control what is going on.
- **Decentralized per namespace** : best of both worlds ?
- **Decentralized per task** : PRO -> scales well, no overhead in management; CONTRA -> what when the version upgrades, what if there's a bug and scheduling did not work properly and you have to correct... sounds like a nightmare. What if scheduling fails ? Can I have a 100% garantuee that a task scheduled a year from now will get exectured ?

Is there somebody out there with good advice/experiences ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not have that customer a year from now, or the terms might change, etc., not to mention all the technical challenges. Schedule in the future approach would not work.

I don't see any difference between the other two approaches, unless you have millions of name spaces.

I don't know how you store your data. Did you consider creating a separate table/entity for invoicing, independent of namespaces? You insert a record there, similar to your "future" approach, and create a cron job to check this table once a day/week/month. If you delete a customer or update the terms, you update this table at that time too.

Comment: Small follow-up question : I can't have transactions over namespaces, right ? so marking a record recurring and saving a bookkeeping record in the global namespace cannot be done in a transaction ?!

Comment: Look at this code: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/multitenancy#Java_Using_namespaces_with_the_Datastore You can use something similar: update an entity in the selected namespace, and create a task to update the global namespace. If this process fails, send a message to admin. It may never happen, but just in case.